# Proving that $\Re(\frac{r}{r-c})\geq 1$ is equivalent to $|c-\frac{r}{2}|\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

For $r, c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|r|=1$ and $|c|\leq 1$, how can we show that $\Re(\frac{r}{r-c})\geq 1$ is equivalent to $|c-\frac{r}{2}|\leq \frac{1}{2}$?

I was working through the proof of a special case of Sendov's conjecture, as given in the book $Complex \ Polynomials$ by T S-Small, and the above equivalence is the last part of the proof, but I have not been able to verify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Re\left(\frac{r}{r-c}\right)\geqslant 1\iff \frac{r}{r-c}+\frac{\bar{r}}{\bar{r}-\bar{c}}\geqslant 2\iff\frac{r(\bar{r}-\bar{c})+\bar{r}(r-c)}{(r-c)(\bar{r}-\bar{c})}\geqslant 2$$Note that $|r|=1$, it's equivalent to the inequality
$$2|c|^2\leqslant r\bar{c}+\bar{r}c\iff \left(c-\frac{r}{2}\right)\left(\bar{c}-\frac{\bar{r}}{2}\right)\leqslant\frac{r\bar{r}}{4}=\frac{1}{4}\iff \left|c-\frac{r}{2}\right|\leqslant \frac{1}{2}$$